# How to select a collection nested within another collection in LINQ

Tags: linq, ef-code-first

Say I have the following:

(--> = 1 to many implemented as a collection in EF code-first)

Message --> UserMessage

Message --> Attachments

When I call the following:

```
var res = _ctx.DataContext.UserMessage.Where(x => x.UserId)
                                      .Select(m => m.Message).ToList();
```

**EDIT: added classes:**

```
public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }      
}



    public class Attachment
    {
        public int AttachmentId { get; set; }

        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public virtual Message Message { get; set; }

        public string FileServerPath { get; set; }
    }



    public class UserMessage
    {
        public int UserMessageId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public Message Message { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }        
    }
```

I would expect the **res** variable to hold all the attachments but it is empty even if there are rows.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where condition doesn't make sense, I don't even think it compiles.
You say, you expect `res` to hold all attachments. Why should it? You don't even use Attachment anywhere in your query.
Without your actual classes, it is a bit hard to suggest the correct way, but I think it would be something like this:

```
var res = _ctx.DataContext.UserMessage.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId)
                                      .SelectMany(m => m.Message.Attachments)
                                      .ToList();
```

Now, `res` contains all attachments of all messages of the user with the id `currentUserId`.

I assumed a class layout like this:

```
class UserMessage
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public Message Message {get;set;}
}

class Message
{
    public IEnumerable<Attachment> Attachments {get;set;}

    // Irrelevant for the query in its current form:
    public IEnumerable<UserMessage> UserMessages {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I've added more classes so as you can see my structure is different to yours. This is in the context of code-first & EF hence the duplication of Ids and tables in the classes to represent the relationships & specify the FKs.

Comment: @jaffa: Please try my code. Your classes are the same than mine regarding the relevant parts.

Comment: I've set it as answered but I ended up implementing it slightly different. My 'aggregate root' is now the Parent class, with the Include() method used on the nested class which in turn holds the collection.

Answer (score 0):

On the context it needs to be told to acquire the navigation properties with an include such as

```
_ctx.UserMessage.Include("Attachments")
                .SelectMany( ... )
```

HTH

Comment: that doesn't look right, why would you include "UserMessage" if you are already querying that off the context?

Comment: @Jaffa Yes you are right one would not get the top level item in an include. ONe only does the sub items, so I have edited the post. thx